# Dynamically Add Rows Based on Condition Using Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

Is it possible that i will be able to add rows based on certain condition in Angular reactive forms? If yes, please help me do it. I've already started it in my stackblitz. Please check this link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows

```
this.addForm.get("items").valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
      if (val === true) {
        this.addForm.get("items_value").setValue("yes");

        // How to add row here?
        this.addForm.addControl(rows, 'rows')
      }
      if (val === false) {
        this.addForm.get("items_value").setValue("no");

        // How to remove row here?
        this.addForm.removeControl(rows, 'rows')
      }
    });
```

Comment: i have a question . u want to add or remove many rows ? or just and or remove one row?

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat. At first, when the condition is met. It should only show one row. But i can also add another row because i will add a button to it.

Comment: i am not sure if i got your problem correctly . i will add an initial answer to your question and see if it solves your issue

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat. Ok. no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the edited stackblitz  :https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-gk4veg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'm sorry i just need many rows. Is it possible to something like this? this.addForm.addControl('rows',new fb:array[]())?

Comment: @Joseph ok . give me a second to update the question

Comment: @Joseph see the link i added

Comment: Can you put in my stackblitz since i want to have based it on the condition. If val is yes, then add that row, if val is no, then remove one row or several rows

Comment: @Joseph if **val** is no , then how should i decide to remove one row , or many rows ?

Comment: Just Remove the rows

Comment: @Joseph i updated the stackbiltz . take a loot at it.

Comment: Good. Please add the button "add row" if there is an existing row, so i can add more row. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph i updated the stackblitz . see if its true .

Comment: @Joseph see if its fine

Comment: yes its good. Can you add inside formArray, Item_name, Item_description and qty?

Comment: @Joseph yeah . i added the changes .

Comment: You have an error in your HTML, this one ---> addForm.get('rows')?.controls. It says  "Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member"

Comment: @Joseph its a bug in stackbiltz . wont affect in runtime

Comment: Can you put remove button in each row? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph thats ez . i added that

Comment: @Joseph hey . yeah but i am not home at the moment . i will check it in a few hours

Comment: Hello. I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot sir