# Angular Reactive Form Array with freeform object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I've been working with Angular for a bit and I know my way decently around Reactive forms and template-driven forms but I am having trouble with this problem, especially Angular's Reactive Form Array.

API response that I wish to POST/PUT to is formed like this, where the user is able to add a row and a dropdown will let them select the property, in this case, it's "p", "h1", "h2" and so on and the value they wished to have typed

```
  "description": {
"body": [
  {
    "p": "test paragraph"
  },
  {
    "h1": "test header"
  }
],
```

I am in the process of converting our old JQuery and js nonsense to a Framework and it has been hard for me to wrap my mind on how to convert this process.

The user will click on Add item:
[image]

Then a row will be created via **formArray** I am assuming since I have tried this beforehand and it has worked but the dropdown to edit the property is giving me an issue.

[image]

And this is how it would look like when a few additional rows are created
[image]

I understand how formArrays work via this example:
[Dynamically Add Rows Based on Condition Using Reactive Forms in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241765/dynamically-add-rows-based-on-condition-using-reactive-forms-in-angular)

so I will need a getter, as well as the function that creates the dynamic form and HTML but I am currently stuck at the moment.

Comment: Also please note that I am doing this in angular 8, with material design and bootstrap 4.
The project is using only reactive forms at the moment for all form submissions

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually figured out most of the problem,
we will be using Angular's FormBuilder, FormArrays, and template interpolation.

Start by defining the form with form builder:

text-form.ts

```
  this.textForm = this.fb.group({
  lang: null,
  description: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

You will be using Angular's getter in this case you want to grab **description** from the defined above form builder

```
  get descriptionItems() {
    return this.artifactTextForm.get('description') as FormArray;
  }
```

Then you will create two functions one is used in a button to **add** rows and the other to delete the current row at the **index** in the Array

This will be a bit different from other examples as we will be using some ES6 tricks

```
  addDescriptionItem() {
this.descriptionItems.push(this.fb.group({[this.selectedHeading]: ''}));
}
```

I defined **this.selectedHeading** as:
at the top of my component class

```
  selectedHeading = 'h1';
```

Now create the button that will be created in the forloop on the template for each row

```
      // deleteDescriptionItem removes the item at the index given in the formArray
  deleteDescriptionItem(index: number) {
    this.descriptionItems.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Now comes one of the most important parts in the template to make sure everything looks nice. I am using **Angular Material Design** but it should work and perform the same natively.

```
    <form [formGroup]="artifactTextForm">

  <mat-dialog-content>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Select Header Type</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(value)]="selectedHeading">
        <mat-option value="h1">Header 1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="h2">Header 2</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="h3">Header 3</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="h4">Header 4</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="p">Paragraph</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- Description form array -->
    <div formArrayName="description">
      <div *ngFor="let item of descriptionItems.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input
          [formControlName]="this.selectedHeading"
          placeholder="Enter Description Data"
          [maxLength]="formMaxLength">
        <button
          mat-raised-button
          color="primary"
          type="button"
          (click)="deleteDescriptionItem(i)">Delete Item</button>
      </div>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addDescriptionItem()">Add Description</button>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>

  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="reset" (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

Make sure the add button is outside of the div with the forloop and it should something like so.

[image]

side note:
Flame shot on ubuntu is amazing.